# Time tuple to a datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert a timestamp tuple from [dpkt](https://code.google.com/p/dpkt/) to a datetime instance.

The timestamp looks like `(seconds, microseconds)`. This is what I am currently doing, but it seems overkill:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
ts = (1296770576, 247792)

ts_list = [str(item) for item in ts]
ts_list[1] = ts_list[1].zfill(6) #make sure we have 6 digits
ts_str = ".".join(ts_list)
ts_float = float(ts_str)
ts_dt = dt.fromtimestamp(ts_float)
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, this is overkill. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the seconds part, then update the datetime object with the microseconds part, using the [`.replace()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
dt.fromtimestamp(ts[0]).replace(microsecond=ts[1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> ts = (1296770576, 247792)
>>> dt.fromtimestamp(ts[0]).replace(microsecond=ts[1])
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 3, 23, 2, 56, 247792)
```

If you did ever have to convert your `(seconds, microseconds)` tuple to a float timestamp, just use floating-point division instead:

```
>>> ts_float = float(ts[0]) + float(ts[1]) / 1000000
>>> dt.fromtimestamp(ts_float)
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 3, 23, 2, 56, 247792)
```